# Integrating unity as library into ios native project, in which both contains Firebase libraries causing Errors

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, unity-game-engine, cocoapods

I have an iOS native project and a Unity project.

**What i am trying to achieve?** - On a button click from the native ios app, i want to show unity in which both the native and ios project contains firebase dependencies.

**What i am actually getting?** - When i try to run the app in xcode, i am getting following errors (almost 4000 similar error but for different Targets):
"Multiple commands produce '/Users/M_742794/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MarkersLab-gpaeablwazuyowbfwysavwxcotrv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/BoringSSL-GRPC/openssl_grpc.framework/Headers/cipher.h':

Target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' (project 'Pods') has copy command from '/Users/M_742794/Developer/iOS/Development/iOS AR Build/Pods/BoringSSL-GRPC/src/include/openssl/cipher.h' to '/Users/M_742794/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MarkersLab-gpaeablwazuyowbfwysavwxcotrv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/BoringSSL-GRPC/openssl_grpc.framework/Headers/cipher.h'

Target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' (project 'Pods') has copy command from '/Users/M_742794/Developer/iOS/Development/unity-AR-Build/Pods/BoringSSL-GRPC/src/include/openssl/cipher.h' to '/Users/M_742794/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MarkersLab-gpaeablwazuyowbfwysavwxcotrv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/BoringSSL-GRPC/openssl_grpc.framework/Headers/cipher.h'"

**Steps i followed for unity integration to my native project** -

1. imported Firebase libraries like Auth, storage, firestore, core in unity and created an iOS build.
2. Podfile has been generated after the build and i installed the firebase pods.
3. I have added the Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj along with its Pods.xcodeproj to my native project workspace with the project structure as below(masked is my native xcodeproj):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNPrG.png)

4. followed the steps mentioned in this uaal link https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/uaal-example/blob/master/docs/ios.md properly like:

   1. Added UnityFramework.framework to the native app general settings framework, libraries and embedded content and removed the same from Build phases Link binary with libraries section.
   2. Added Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj's Data folder target membership to UnityFramework.
   3. Added Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj's NativeCallProxy file target membership to UnityFramework with public access.
   4. made code changes in native project to show unity on button click.
5. I have firebase dependencies in my native xcode project as well as unity xcode project and the podfiles are as below:

   - Unity Xcode project Podfile:
     [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIDFw.png)
   - Native Xcode project Podfile:
     [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxbQm.png)
6. I have installed the pods for both the projects and started building in xcode.
7. The build is failing with number of "Multiple commands produce" errors:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SN2ij.png)
8. The errors might be causing due to firebase dependency in both native and unity projects but could not find proper solution for this issue.

I am expecting solutions from this group for my problem, Thanks!

Comment: You should detail the specific errors you are getting here, otherwise there is not a lot to go on without looking at third-party sites, which could change over time.

Comment: @cchamberlain Hi, I have edited the question.

Comment: Tried deleting the derived data but it didnt solved the problem.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question now that additional information has been provided

Comment: any solution for this issue

Comment: @mychar Sorry as i noticed your comment late. I have restructured my Podfile as a solution for this issue and is working perfect. Ill share the format here for anyone whose facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the format used in podfile for installing common pods for both targets and standalone for specific targets.

workspace ‘//workspace_name//’

def common_pods()
// pods for both native and unity
end

def native_pods()
// pods for native
end

abstract_target 'CommonPods' do

```
target 'UnityFramework' do
    project ‘// project_path//’
    use_frameworks!
    
    common_pods()
end

target ‘//native_project_target//‘ do
  project ‘//native_project_name//‘
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  
  common_pods()
  native_pods()
  
end
```

end